# update or replace the mongoose nested array object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a timesheet schema which results as below and I want to replace single **data** array object by a new set of values in mongoose. Either i want remove already existing object and push a new set of values or update the old object with new values.Please suggest me a proper way to achieve this. I am was struggled a lot to do this, because i am new to mongoose and mongodb. Thanks in advance

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("53f1fb3401ea96440d62646b"),
    "user_id": "andrew",
    "type": "Solutions",
    "timesheets": [{
            "weekStartDate": ISODate("2014-08-18T00:00:00Z"),
            "weekEndDate": ISODate("2014-08-22T00:00:00Z"),
            "_id": ObjectId("53f1fb3401ea96440d62646c"),
            "data": [{
                    "date": ISODate("2014-08-18T00:00:00Z"),
                    "_id": ObjectId("53f1fb3401ea96440d62646d"),
                    "record": [{
                            "_id": ObjectId("53f1fb3401ea96440d626470"),
                            "desc": "",
                            "cellId": "0:0",
                            "custName": "Coach",
                            "custID": "2",
                            "timeSpend": "04:00",
                            "categoryName": "Billing",
                            "categoryID": "1"
                    }, {
                            "_id": ObjectId("53f1fb3401ea96440d62646f"),
                            "desc": "Description",
                            "cellId": "0:1",
                            "custName": "",
                            "custID": "",
                            "timeSpend": "05:00",
                            "categoryName": "Solution",
                            "categoryID": "4"
                    }, {
                            "_id": ObjectId("53f1fb3401ea96440d62646e"),
                            "desc": "Description",
                            "cellId": "0:2",
                            "custName": "",
                            "custID": "",
                            "timeSpend": "06:00",
                            "categoryName": "GTM",
                            "categoryID": "3"
                    }],
                    "savedFlag": false,
                    "submitFlag": false
            }, {
                    "date": ISODate("2014-08-19T00:00:00Z"),
                    "_id": ObjectId("53f1fb4e01ea96440d626471"),
                    "record": [{
                            "_id": ObjectId("53f1fb4e01ea96440d626474"),
                            "desc": "",
                            "cellId": "1:0",
                            "custName": "Morgan",
                            "custID": "3",
                            "timeSpend": "04:00",
                            "categoryName": "RFP",
                            "categoryID": "2"
                    }, {
                            "_id": ObjectId("53f1fb4e01ea96440d626473"),
                            "desc": "",
                            "cellId": "1:1",
                            "custName": "Morgan",
                            "custID": "3",
                            "timeSpend": "05:00",
                            "categoryName": "RFP",
                            "categoryID": "2"
                    }, {
                            "_id": ObjectId("53f1fb4e01ea96440d626472"),
                            "desc": "",
                            "cellId": "1:2",
                            "custName": "Citi",
                            "custID": "1",
                            "timeSpend": "04:00",
                            "categoryName": "Sales",
                            "categoryID": "0"
                    }],
                    "savedFlag": false,
                    "submitFlag": false
            }],
            "savedFlag": true,
            "submitFlag": false
    }],
    "__v": 0
```

} >

Comment: Can you give an example document, description of the operation you want to perform, and output document for the two different things you're trying to achieve? I'm not quite sure what you want to do.

Comment: I want to update single object of an array with new set of values "update{'timesheets.data[0]':replace with new data values}" or update{'timesheets.data.record[0]':replace with new record values}

Comment: Could you edit the question with a document as you would like it to be after the update and with what you have tried so far?

Comment: I want to remove the single array element from (data array) after that i want insert the new values to the array or update old array element with new values. Roughly like this Timesheets.update({'id':timsheets.data._id},{$pull:'timesheets.data'{'id':data.id}}})